# how to clear the array (this.array) of the bufferAttribute which is shared with different geometries

Tags: three.js

can anyone help me out, how to clear the array (this.array) of the bufferAttribute which is shared with different geometries.
i tried with "onUploadCallback" but it throwing error for this case.

```
getBufferAttrib(accessor)
{
let key ='bufferView : ' + accessor.bufferView;
let bufferAttribute = this.BufferAttributeCache.get(key);

if(bufferAttribute === undefined){

    let itemSize = WebglConstants.WEBGL_TYPE_SIZES[accessor.type];

    let arrayType = WebglConstants.WEBGL_COMPONENT_TYPES[accessor.componentType];
    let data = new arrayType(accessor.bufferViewData,accessor.bufferOffset, accessor.count * itemSize );
    bufferAttribute = new THREE.BufferAttribute( data, itemSize );    
    bufferAttribute.name = accessor.name;
    bufferAttribute.refCount = 1;
    bufferAttribute.onUploadCallback = function() {
        this.refCount = this.refCount - 1;
        if(this.refCount === 0){
            this.array = null;
        }             
    };      
    this.BufferAttributeCache.add(key, bufferAttribute);

}
else{
    bufferAttribute.refCount = bufferAttribute.refCount + 1;
}
```

Comment: If you're receiving an error, please include the full text of the error in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure you can just delete the array after uploading it like this... why are you trying to "clear" it? This code doesn't show how it's shared with other attributes.

Comment: This is one example where `BufferAttribute.onUpload()` is used: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry. If you never touch the geometry data again after uploading, you can save some memory by setting the reference of `BufferAttribute.array` to `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: You could also use one typed array ever to upload all the attributes I think. This should all help memory management on the js side of things.

Comment: Did you render this at least once before trying to clear?

Comment: @TheJim01 : the error message what i am getting is this                                                                                     
 three.js:10679 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at BufferAttribute.getX (three.js:10679)
    at Box3.setFromBufferAttribute (three.js:4796)
    at BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere (three.js:11783)
    at Frustum.intersectsObject (three.js:5828)
    at projectObject (three.js:23297)
    at projectObject (three.js:23342)
    at projectObject (three.js:23342)
    at projectObject (three.js:23342)

Comment: @pailhead :no that was the problem. now i managed to clear the array of all the BufferAttribute in the "onAfterRendering" callback function of the scene object. I don't know, is this a right approach for clearing the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided, especially the call stack, it appears this happens during the render.

Within `WebGLRenderer.render`, there is an internal function named `projectObject`, which contains this line (r95):

```
if ( ! object.frustumCulled || _frustum.intersectsObject( object ) ) {
```

The frustum intersection check tries to intersect with the object's `boundingSphere`, and will generate said `boundingSphere` if it is not available. This generation needs to reference the vertex buffer, which--in your case--is no longer there.

To avoid this problem, simply compute the `boundingSphere` of each object before discarding its buffers. When the frustum intersection occurs, it will find the sphere and pass/fail the test, rather than encountering an error trying to create the sphere.